# User Session Management with Spring

Tags: java, spring, session-state

I am developing a flex java - spring web app and have set up the business logic using hibernate.

I want to maintain sessions so that when the user logs in , i can track the logged in user to display information that is related to the username.

I want to do this using spring if possible and wondered if anyone could redirect me to a tutorial or even explain the method to which this is achieved , or if it is hard to achieve.

Thanks 
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security is the framework that you need and yes it's very straight forward. A simple search on Google will give you plenty of help but this is a great starting point: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html